# Finding Cordinates of Cap of an arrow

Tags: c++, math, geometry

I have to draw an arrow. I have a head point and a tail point now i need to draw a triangular arrow cap. A triangle whose length is of size 5.How can i find coordinates of the end points of triangle. One thing is we have angle of 45.so if we can rotate the vector by 45 to obtain it.
`   int x1=arrowStart.X;
    int y1=arrowStart.Y;
    int x2=arrowend.X;
    int y2=arrowend.Y;

```
PointF arrowPoint=arrowend;

double arrowlength=sqrt(pow(x1-x2,2)+pow(y1-y2,2));

int ArrowMultiplier=1;
double arrowangle=atan2(y1-y2,x1-x2);

double pointx,pointy; 
if(x1>x2)
{
    pointx=x1 - (cos(arrowangle) * (arrowlength-3 * ArrowMultiplier ));
}
else
{
    pointx = cos(arrowangle) * (arrowlength-3 * ArrowMultiplier ) + x1;
}

if (y1 > y2)
{
    pointy = y1 - (sin(arrowangle) * (arrowlength -3 * ArrowMultiplier));
}
else
{
    pointy = (sin(arrowangle) * (arrowlength-3 * ArrowMultiplier )) + y1;
}

PointF arrowPointBack(pointx,pointy);
double angleB = atan2((3 * ArrowMultiplier), (arrowlength - (3 * ArrowMultiplier)));

 double angleC = (3.14) * (90 - (arrowangle * (180 /3.14)) - (angleB * (180 / 3.14))) / 180;


 double secondaryLength = (3 * ArrowMultiplier)/sin(angleB);

  if (x1 > x2)
{
    pointx = x1 - (sin(angleC) * secondaryLength);
}
else
{
    pointx = (sin(angleC) * secondaryLength) + x1;
}

if (y1 > y2)
{
    pointy = y1 - (cos(angleC) * secondaryLength);
}
else
{
    pointy = (cos(angleC) * secondaryLength) + y1;
}

PointF arrowPointLeft((float)pointx, (float)pointy);
 angleC = arrowangle - angleB;

if (x1 > x2)
{
    pointx = x1 - (cos(angleC) * secondaryLength);
}
else
{
    pointx = (cos(angleC) * secondaryLength) +x1;
}

if (y1 > y2)
{
    pointy =y1 - (sin(angleC) * secondaryLength);
}
else
{
    pointy = (sin(angleC) * secondaryLength) + y1;
}

PointF arrowPointRight((float)pointx,(float)pointy);
PointF arrowPoints[4];
arrowPoints[0] = arrowPoint;
arrowPoints[1] = arrowPointLeft;
//arrowPoints[2] = arrowPointBack;
arrowPoints[2] = arrowPointRight;
arrowPoints[3] = arrowPoint;
```

`

Comment: Yeah sure i will.If u give me algorithm also i will code it myself.Steps are enough

Comment: You could calculate coordinates for horizontal arrow, then apply affine transform with rotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, I suppose I should break it down for you:

First, you need to calculate the angle that the arrow sits at.  This can be achieved with the inverse tangent function:

```
atan(diff_y, diff_x)
```

where diff_y and diff_x are the difference between the x and y values of your two end-points.

You can then add the desired angle of the arrow-head to this angle and use `sin` and `cos` to calculate the `x` and `y` values of the first of the extra points of the arrow-head.

```
new_x = head_x - 5 * cos (angle + pi/4)
new_y = head_y + 5 * sin (angle + pi/4)
```

for the other point, you do the same, but with a subtraction of the difference in angle.

```
new_x = head_x - 5 * cos (angle - pi/4)
new_y = head_y + 5 * sin (angle - pi/4)
```

You then have all the points you need.

I did this for fun (sue me, I was bored) and came up with this:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>

const double arrow_head_length = 3;
const double PI = 3.14159265;
const double arrow_head_angle = PI/6;

//returns the angle between two points, with coordinate1 describing the centre of the circle, with the angle progressing clockwise
double angle_between_points( std::pair<double,double> coordinate1,  std::pair<double,double> coordinate2)
{
  return atan2(coordinate2.second - coordinate1.second, coordinate1.first - coordinate2.first);
}

//calculate the position of a new point [displacement] away from an original point at an angle of [angle]
std::pair<double,double> displacement_angle_offset(std::pair<double,double> coordinate_base, double displacement, double angle)
{
    return std::make_pair
    (
        coordinate_base.first  - displacement * cos(angle),
        coordinate_base.second + displacement * sin(angle)
    );
}

int main()
{
  std::pair<double,double> arrow_tail( 0, 0);
  std::pair<double,double> arrow_head( 15,-15);

  //find the angle of the arrow
  double angle = angle_between_points(arrow_head, arrow_tail);

  //calculate the new positions
  std::pair<double,double> head_point_1 = displacement_angle_offset(arrow_head, arrow_head_length, angle + arrow_head_angle);
  std::pair<double,double> head_point_2 = displacement_angle_offset(arrow_head, arrow_head_length, angle - arrow_head_angle);

  //output the points in order: tail->head->point1->point2->head so if you follow them it draws the arrow
  std::cout << arrow_tail.first   << ',' << arrow_tail.second   << '\n'
            << arrow_head.first   << ',' << arrow_head.second   << '\n'
            << head_point_1.first << ',' << head_point_1.second << '\n'
            << head_point_2.first << ',' << head_point_2.second << '\n'
            << arrow_head.first   << ',' << arrow_head.second   << std::endl;
}
```

The output can be saved as a `.csv` and loaded into excel for example, where you can use it to draw a connected scatter-graph that will form the shape of the arrow.

If this is homework, then before you do anything with it, **make sure you know exactly how it works**.  That includes knowing the answers to questions like:

- when calculating the angle, why does the code do `point2_y-point1_y` but `point1_x-point2_x`?
- what direction is angle `0`?
- why does the angle increase going clockwise and not anti-clockwise?
- why are there 5 outputs when only 4 points are needed?
- what is the significance of `PI/6` in the code? It isn't == 45 degrees. Why would this angle be better?

Also note that this question and answer will now pop up in a google search.

Working example: http://ideone.com/D4IwOy

You can paste the output into any graphing tool [(such as this one)](http://www.alcula.com/calculators/statistics/scatter-plot/) or save as a `.csv` and open in excel/spreadsheet of choice and plot a scatter graph to see the arrow coordinates. Note that it (annoyingly) doesn't keep the `x` and `y` scales equal so will stretch arrows like this one:

```
3,7
24,15
21.0381,15.4768
22.1061,12.6734
24,15
```

Comment: Yeah thank you ..its not a homework.Problem is was not getting how to start thank you

Comment: Not homework, ok.  But still try and answer those questions, it's never a good idea to use code that you don't know how it works.

Comment: Yes i would vote..but still i m facing issues regarding angle.

Comment: Have you figured it out now? Try using the functions I've written in the code above `angle_between_points` and `displacement_angle_offset` (possibly not the best names) as they should help make your code simpler and easier to read.  If you provide a runable sample, I'd find it easier to help too.